# Collect specific key's value from List of Maps List<String,

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-stream

I am parsing the JSON response from server in Java class. We have utility function to covert JSON to `List<Map<String, Object>>`.
Now I want to collect specific key's value from all objects. For example the JSON I receive is person's data like below

```
[
 {
   name:'abc',
   city: 'Hyd'
 },
 {
   name:'def',
   city:'NYC'
 }
]
```

I wanted to try Java8 stream API to get this job done, so here is how i wrote

```
List<Map<String,Object>> answer = parseJSONReponse(response);
List<Object> collect = answer.stream().map(
            m -> m.entrySet().stream()
                             .filter(e-> e.getKey().equals("name"))
                             .map(e -> e.getValue())
                             .collect(Collectors.toList())
    ).flatMap(l->l.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Please let me know if there is better of writing this stream API.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to `collect` inside `map`, then `flatMap` as you're creating unnecessary intermediate lists. Just use `flatMap` directly:

```
List<Object> collect = answer.stream().flatMap(
            m -> m.entrySet().stream()
                             .filter(e-> e.getKey().equals("name"))
                             .map(e -> e.getValue())
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Is it possible to get list of another types (Long for example), not Object?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using a parallel stream.

> Note that parallelism is not automatically faster than performing operations serially, although it can be if you have enough data and processor cores. While aggregate operations enable you to more easily implement parallelism, it is still your responsibility to determine if your application is suitable for parallelism. [1]

This can be easily done by exchanging the `stream()` methods with `parallelStream()`.

[1] [Oracle tutorial on stream parallelism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html).